# Warning message says that a value "can only be null". It should be filled from Reader.Read(Char[])

Tags: java, android, string, file-io, filereader

It gives a message saying: "Null pointer access: The variable CharacterList can only be null at this location", when I think it should be filled from the `FileReader.Read()` method:

```
public String[] ReadPeopleFile(String[] PeopleList, FileReader PeopleReader){
    char CharacterList[];///Soon parsed into a string list, by delimiting and separating into two string arrays,
    CharacterList = null;   
    String ParseString = null;
    try {
        PeopleReader.read(CharacterList);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ParseString = CharacterList.toString();
    PeopleList = ParseString.split(";");

    return PeopleList;
}
```

Comment: The warning is at the line: "ParseString = CharacterList.toString();"

Comment: That's eclipse saying that your variable is never assigned to anything but null. Eclipse isn't smart enough to realize that your CharacterList is going to be written to in another method. It's just a warning to let you know in case you forgot to assign a variable along the way. Your app should still compile and run fine (provided your read(..) call works right)

Comment: @dymmeh Eclipse is correct, CharacterList cannot be anything but null in this code.

Comment: Please don't start variable names with an upper case letter.  iT mAKES yOUR cODE dIIFICULT tO rEAD.

Comment: Ok, thanks!! I can see why that happened.. :)

Comment: @CharlesForsythe - you're right. he'd need to at least initialize it first. good call

Comment: @CharlesForsythe, why can it only be null?? Surely by passing it through the method, it will be returned with characters in??

Comment: @dymmeh I think the improper camel-case makes the code sample difficult to follow.

Comment: ok... how do I initialize it??? i thought by declaring it as null, that would initialize it??

Comment: @SwedishArchitect Java passes by value.  You are not "passing it through" this method.  When you call the method, the value that is assigned to `characterList` will be passed to the method `read`.  This, again is the *value*, not some kind of *reference* to `characterList`.  If `characterList` had a value of null, then `read` will receive that value (and probably throw an Exception).  Either way, it cannot assign `characterList` because `characterList` is not in its scope.

Comment: @SwedishArchitect See my code sample below for an example of how to initialize it.  You have initialized `characterList`, but you have initialized it to null, and there is no code that changes its value.

Comment: Ok, I've only recently started learning Java, and thought it passed by reference. On the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Reader.html , it says that reader.read(char[] buf) is one way to use reader. what's the difference between what I'm doing and that?? thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CharacterList is not going to be assigned unless you assign it.  You need something more like this:

```
char characterList[] = new char[1000]; // I'm assuming that 1000 is enough here
int numChars = peopleReader.read(characterList); // I've changed PeopleReader to proper camel-case
String parseString = new String(characterList, 0, numChars);
```

I'm actually skipping some details here. You should really look at the API documentation for `FileReader` and maybe find some file reading examples.

Comment: ok... that's making sense. I guess i should stop using camel-case... Thanks!!

Comment: @SwedishArchitect You should use [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)